# Multithread processing with RedisQueueInboundGateway

Tags: spring, multithreading, redis, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration with Redis. The producer uses RedisQueueOutboundGateway and on the other side the receiver have a flow defined with RedisQueueInboundGateway.

Reading from the documentation I found the following sentence

> The task-executor has to be configured with more than one thread for processing

My need is to have concurrent executions, in order to speed up the elaboration of requests, but I can see there is always one thread even if I configured a custom ThreadPoolTaskExecutor like the following

```
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(40);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(40);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("QueueAsyncExecutor-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

and the use of this threadpool is

```
final RedisQueueInboundGateway rqig = new RedisQueueInboundGateway(finalDestination, jedisConnectionFactory);
rqig.setTaskExecutor(getAsyncExecutor());
```

The final result is a sequential processing of the requests, all done with the same thread as i can see from the log. Is it possible to enable the multithread processing in that situation? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. The `RedisQueueInboundGateway` is a single-threaded for now. There is only one `ListenerTask`:

```
private void restart() {
    this.taskExecutor.execute(new ListenerTask());
}
```

Sounds like we need to introduce `concurrency` option into that `RedisQueueInboundGateway`! Feel free to raise a JIRA on the matter and contribution is welcome!

You may achieve an artificial concurrency with several `RedisQueueInboundGateway` instances for the same Redis queue. This way each of them will start its own `ListenerTask`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Is it correct to simulate the concurrency the use of RedisInboundChannelAdapter (that can be multi-thread) and finally with a custom flow adding a message to redis with ".reply", so the caller with RedisQueueOutboundGateway can read it ?

Comment: Yes, you can play with that as well. Only the problem that `RedisQueueInboundGateway` has some hard logic around UUIDs for requests to pop.

Comment: Taking advantage of your kindness, can you tell me why I found  Redis Queue Inbound Channel Adapter in the documentation and it's available as xml entity (int-redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter) but I didn't find a Java DSL equivalent